# Batch file - cannot strip variable in sub routine

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am struggling with a Windows batch file, which will be run at SERVER in intervals  and will evaluate all computers in network, then pull new and changed files to backup NAS device. I decided for such approach to have only 1 script to maintain against 150 backups on 150 computers.

The problem I have is I need to extract computer NAME, which I store in .txt file as:

**Name:   computername.domain.name**
to pure computer name:

**computername.domain.name**

I did this by pulling .txt file content into VARIABLE, then I strip first 9 characters off in SUB-routine **:SUBfound**:

```
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 for /L %%i in (0,1,255) do (call :SUBscan 192.168.79.%%i)

:SUBscan ip
 echo|set /p dummyOutput="Scanning %1 ... "
 ping -n 1 -w 200 -4 %1 >nul
 if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (echo not a computer) else (
   if exist "\\%1\d$\DataFolder\" (call :SUBfound %1) else (call :SUBnotfound %1)
 )
 EXIT /B

:SUBfound
 set targetname=<backup_id.txt
 set "targetname=!targetname:~9!"
 ...other code
EXIT /B
```

But targetname in :SUBfound does not evaluate:

```
 echo !targetname!  -->  echoes me:~9!
 echo %targetname%  -->  echoes !targetname!
```

I know there must be something wrong with SET evaluation of variables in sub-routines, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: `set /p targetname=<backup_id.txt`?

Comment: You should show the real code of your `:SubFound`, because your results doesn't fit to your code. You could also test the content of `targetname` with `set targetname`, that shows the real content of the variable unmodified

Comment: MC ND thanx, that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MC ND diagnosed your problem in his comment.

You cannot read a file with a simple `SET`, you must use `SET /P` instead.

```
set /p "targetname=" <backup_id.txt
```

But there is another way using FOR /F that allows you to read the value directly in one step. Set DELIMS to a colon and space, and TOKENS to 2.

Assuming your file has only one line, then

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%A in (backup_id.txt) do set "targetname=%%A"
```

If there are multiple lines, and the value is in the first line, then

```
set "targetname="
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%A in (backup_id.txt) do if not defined targetname set "targetname=%%A"
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%A in (backup_id.txt) do set "targetname=%%A" & goto skip
:skip
```

Comment: MC ND and DBEnham...thank you both for exact answers and clarification. SET /p works like a charm. Regarding 2nd part of your suggestion, dbenham, it would come handy, if I would not need to first evaluate alive devices on network (with PING), then check if they have either c:\Users\... or D:\DataFolder\ configured for "MyDocuments" and "Desktop", and finally run Robocopy on changed files via network to NAS storage. All works fine now after I adjusted variable reading from file. Thanx!